# Can I use a variable to store a linkedServer name and then use that to directly query databases on that Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently have code in a script that, looks something like:

```
 SELECT * FROM [linkedServerName].database1.dbo.tableA;
 SELECT * FROM [linkedServerName].database1.dbo.tableB;
 SELECT * FROM [linkedServerName].database1.dbo.tableC;
```

except that it's not as neat as this and in reality there are references scattered all over a very long script.

I will need to run this script on a number of different test environments where the name of the linkedServer will need to change.

Is there a way that I can store these in a single variable so that I only need to make 1 adjustment?

(I tried to use a Synonym but it seems that I can only do that at a table level, so I would need multiples of them which defeats the purpose of what I am trying to achieve.)

Comment: Not without dynamic SQL.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible by using sqlcmd variables in database project
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/add-database-reference-dialog-box?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=a%20composite%20project-,In%20Solution%20Explorer%2C%20right%20click%20References%20and%20select%20Add%20Database,and%20paste%20it%20into%20your%20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/add-database-reference-dialog-box?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=a%20composite%20project-,In%20Solution%20Explorer%2C%20right%20click%20References%20and%20select%20Add%20Database,and%20paste%20it%20into%20your%20).
The DACPAC along with the cmdvariable can be used to achieve your requirement

Comment: Thanks but that appears to be related to SSDT work. I am just using a basic script that will be executed via SSMS - not an SSIS package.

Comment: Hey @sperick, Then dynamic SQL is your answer. Create a variable which would change based on environment and conact it with remaining query.then execute it via exec statement